# Переодические операции в течении lifecycle Activity

Tags: android

Мне нужно организовать запуск пары операций каждые n секунд, пока Activity на экране. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: lifecycle чего?

Comment: самый простой вариант - запуск таймера (или handler  + runnable) в onStart и destroy в onStop.

Comment: Да хороший вариант. Сделайте коммент ответом, я его приму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложенный в комментариях вариант:

```
самый простой вариант - запуск таймера (или handler + runnable) в onStart и destroy в onStop.
```

Оказался довольно простым и хорошим решением проблемы.